# Can't run django tests by tag

Tags: python, django, testing

I have problem because I wanted to tag some test in django but when I type in console

```
from django.test import tag, TestCase


@tag('fast', 'something')
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do something

    def test_something(self):
        # do something
```

when I type in console:

```
./manage.py test --tag=fast -k
```

I got:

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
```

example module structure:

```
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
├── models.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── test_views.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: Can you please share your project's file structure?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis,  I assumed you wanted to see how located are my test files so I edited my question for example module file structure

Comment: Which version of django? This is available only in 1.10 onwards

Comment: @e4c5 I'm using django 1.11

Comment: hm, curious. Can you try without the keep flag?

Comment: I tried it before asking here, same effect

Comment: this happened to me too, and I think it is because there's some python error in one of your tests. 1 year later may not be useful, but ‾\_(ツ)_/‾

Answer (score 1):

Check that there is not a syntax error or bad import in your test files. I had a bad import and it silently failed with `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have changed the `TEST_RUNNER` in your settings.py

We'd had [django-nose](https://pypi.org/project/django-nose) installed. I didn't realize we were not using the default test runner and spent ages trying to figure out why my tags were not working. This post kept coming up when I was searching.

Comment: This was exactly my problem